# My matrix multiplication is not working how i expect

Tags: c++, directx, direct3d, matrix-multiplication, transpose

This is what I want:

[image]

What am I doing wrong with the following code. The output of the translation for the orbit rotation never occurs, it just ends up rotating all on the original axis.

```
void Renderer::UpdateAsteroid( Placement^ asteroidRotation, Placement^ sceneOrientation )
{
    XMMATRIX selfRotation;

    // Rotate the asteroid
    selfRotation = XMMatrixRotationX( asteroidRotation->GetRotX() );
    selfRotation = XMMatrixMultiply( selfRotation, XMMatrixRotationY( asteroidRotation->GetRotY() ) );  
    selfRotation = XMMatrixMultiply( selfRotation, XMMatrixRotationZ( asteroidRotation->GetRotZ() ) );

    XMMATRIX translation;

    // Move the asteroid to new location
    translation = XMMatrixTranslation( sceneOrientation->GetPosX(), sceneOrientation->GetPosY(), sceneOrientation->GetPosZ() );

    XMMATRIX orbitRotation;

    // Rotate from moved origin
    orbitRotation = XMMatrixRotationZ( sceneOrientation->GetRotZ() );

    XMMATRIX outputMatrix = selfRotation * translation * orbitRotation;

    // Store
    XMStoreFloat4x4( &m_constantBufferData.model, XMMatrixTranspose( outputMatrix ) );
}
```

but it does not seem to work.. it just ends up rotating on the same point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Matrix multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication) is **not commutative**, i.e. changing operands order changes result.
Typically you will want to calculate all of your matrces and then multiply together. Try this order first:

```
result = scale * selfRotation * translation * orbitRotation
```

If it's not what you want, just move matrices around to find right order.

Note, XMMath also have [`XMMatrixRotationRollPitchYaw()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.directx_sdk.matrix.xmmatrixrotationrollpitchyaw%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to get rotation matrices in one call.

Comment: I've given it a shot, latest update in OP - P.S i'm stealing your wording (orbitRotation), much better than my "sceneRotation" :D

Comment: DONT WORRY, GOT IT. thanks for your help dude! I was doing something stupid :D